# How to effectively remove an item from the cart on shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware6

I am trying to prevent products with different properties from been mixed up in the cart.

To do that I have set some conditions and I am displaying some notices to the user on the cart, but I need to be able to remove items that I make a notice about.

At the moment, I am setting up logic

```php
public function onLineItemAdded(AfterLineItemAddedEvent $event): void
    {
        $lineItems = $event->getLineItems();
        $shipperExists = false;
        foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
            $this->processCustomFields($lineItem);
            if (isset($lineItem->getPayload()["customFields"]["dropper_"])) {
                $shipperExists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$shipperExists && isset($this->customFields["dropper_"])) {
            $this->flashBag->add(
                "info",
                "Invalid entry, You are trying to include a product without dropshipping option to a product with a dropshipping option."
            );         
        }
        if ($shipperExists && !isset($this->customFields["dropper_"]) && isset($this->customFields)) {
            $this->flashBag->add(
                "info",
                "Invalid entry, You are trying to include a product with dropshipping option to a product without a dropshipping option."
            );
        }
    }
```

and I then tried to use a cartservice.

`use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartService;`

`$cart = $cartService->getCart($contextToken);`

`$cart = $cartService->delete($cart, $lineItemId, $context);`

but I am unable to delete the cart item. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `remove` method from `LineItemCollection` class. I did this in my Subscriber for `BeforeLineItemAddedEvent` and `BeforeLineItemRemovedEvent`.

```
$cart = $event->getCart();
$products = $cart->getLineItems();

foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    if ($yourCondition) {
        $products->remove($key);
        $cart->setLineItems($products);
    }
}
```

If you want to use the `cartService` the method is called `remove` as well, not `delete`. `$identifier` is the line item key, not the productId

```
public function remove(Cart $cart, string $identifier, SalesChannelContext $context): Cart
```